# Convert C++ 11 code map with pair into C++ 03

Tags: c++, c++11, c++03

how can i convert C++ 11 code map with pair into C++ 03

```
    std::map<string, pair<CO3d*, DWORD>> Entities;
    std::map<string, pair<CO3d*, DWORD>> Objects;
    std::map<string, pair<CO3d*, DWORD>> Others;
```

trying to load

```
        Entities[] = { pO3D, 10 };
        Objects[] = { pO3D, 10 };
        Others[] = { pO3D, 10 };
```

and get syntax error

```
syntax error : {
```

```
syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```

Answer (score 4):

You have to put a space between consecutive `>`s for specifying template arguments in C++03.

```
    std::map<string, pair<CO3d*, DWORD> > Entities;
    std::map<string, pair<CO3d*, DWORD> > Objects;
    std::map<string, pair<CO3d*, DWORD> > Others;
```

Comment: Now that's something you won't find in the MS Compiler Conformance Table...

Comment: i still have an error

Comment: ```
syntax error : {
syntax error : missing ';' before '{'
```
get this error

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin of course it doesn't, because that's a [new feature in C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Right_angle_bracket). There's nothing nonconforming regarding `>>` in templates so MS doesn't list it

Comment: @phuclv I apologize, I was unclear, I wasn't speaking of the actual right-shift difference, I was referring to what you find listed in [Microsoft C++ language conformance table](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/overview/visual-cpp-language-conformance?view=msvc-160)